# Clojurescript: merging two maps produces a list of two maps, instead of a single map with the new values

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Attempting to write a function which takes a `url`, `api-key` and an optional map of query parameters.

This code works if there are no query params:

```
(defn get-api
  [url api-key & query]
  (let [api-map {:apikey api-key}]
    (let [params (if query
                  (merge query api-map)
                  api-map)]
      (.log js/console (pr-str params))
      (GET url {:params params}))))

(get-api "some/url" "some-key") ;works just fine
(get-api "some/url" "some-key" {:id 123}) ;ends up producing ({:apikey "some-key"} {:id 123})
```

What am I missing to produce a single map with the values I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destructuring `[x & y]` guarantees that y will be a sequence of all args after the first. If you just want to have a single optional argument, use multiple arities instead. Also, your `if` is not needed - nil (or an empty map, as I use below) will merge just fine.

```
(defn get-api
  ([url api-key] (get-api url api-key {}))
  ([url api-key query]
   (let [params (merge query {:api-key api-key})]
     ...)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it, and let me understand how I can use some optional params for later.